# "It...that" sentence structure

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax

I have one question!.

It's obvious through the photographs the journalist brings back from the field that he shows the situation he witnessed.

It looks like weird! Do we need to start "He shows the situation"? Is this real subject?

If so, can you give me more examples? like It ~ that~ structure

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to say that 'the photographs the journalist brings back... show the situation'?

Answer (score 1):

The structure is quite common

> It is known that the sky is blue.
>
> It is said that Libras make good lovers
>
> It is obvious that water and oil don't mix.

These are a passive form of a sentence like

> John knows that the sky is blue.

The use of the passive, with a dummy subject "It" is to say that state that "some people" or "everybody" knows, or says something without giving a specfic source

The use with an adjective like "obvious" or "clear" can be expressed actively as

> People obviously know that he shows the situation he witnessed...

Comment: +1 Another active way to say the same thing: "The journalist's photos clearly show that ..."